# How to include custom files in JAR with Maven assembly plugin jar-with-dependencies

Tags: maven, pom.xml, maven-assembly-plugin

I need to include custom file (/com/app/log4.properties) in a final JAR.

How can I add one file to my JAR when using jar-with-dependencies?

Now there are only class files in that JAR. I'm using:

```
mvn assembly:assembly
```

My pom.xml:

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.app.Start</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                    <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put non-Java files that need to be in the final artifact in `src/main/resources`, in this case:

```
src/main/resources/com/app/log4j.properties
```

Comment: what if the file is located somewhere in the filesystem?

Comment: @Enerccio What if? Then you set up your log4j to use an external config file.

Comment: I am trying to include a jar from jdk transparently and without fuss

Comment: @Enerccio This seems like a completely unrelated question; perhaps searching or posting a new one. But if it's from the JDK you shouldn't need to do that.