# How to include log4j.properties in JAR

Tags: java, lambda, log4j

I am trying to make a AWS Lambda Function and you can only upload a JAR. I know that normally I could keep the log property file in the target directory and the jar would reference it but how would I be able to include it in the jar so that the program doesn't look for this external property file?

Comment: If you are using maven to generate the jar, then put the property file into src/main/resources directory. It will include it to the jar automatically. IMHO putting the file manually into the target directory is some kind of workaround.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to include custom files in JAR with Maven assembly plugin jar-with-dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15591742/how-to-include-custom-files-in-jar-with-maven-assembly-plugin-jar-with-dependenc)